# Printing the full exception

Tags: python, exception

I don't know what it's called, but when I'm in the python live interpreter, I get a trail of statements in the form 'File , line ' etc, showing all the places where something went wrong so I can pinpoint the origin. Is this information an attribute of the exception that I can access? I'm looking for some solution like:

```
try:
     do_something_wrong()
except Exception as e: 
     print e.really_useful_information
```

What should I use as 'really_useful_information'? If it isn't possible, how else could I access this information while continuing to run the program?

Comment: The information you're referring to is known as a "traceback".  There is a [traceback module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#module-traceback) which might do what you want, although I have not tried it myself.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [traceback.print_exc()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc):

```
import traceback
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called a *stack trace*, if I understand you correctly.
Take a look at the *traceback* module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html Specifically traceback.print_exception() and traceback.print_exc().